# Permanent set of results in specific field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this is really obvious, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to work out the right combination of words to search properly....so, apologies if this has been asked before.

So say I have a simple table with 4 fields: Product, Continent, Month, sales. I want to show total sales for each Product, Continent, Month BUT I always want to show EVERY Continent regardless if there were sales that Month or not. So For every combination of Product and Month I ALWAYS want the 7 continents listed.

I've tried various joins and CTEs but It seems I can't find the right combination to only pull null values at the Continent level.

Data Example:

```
Product Continent   Month   Sales
A       Asia        SEP     ###
A       America     SEP     ###
A       Europe      OCT     ###
A       Africa      AUG     ###
A       Oceania     OCT     ###
B       Europe      SEP     ###
B       Africa      SEP     ###
C       America     AUG     ###
C       Oceania     AUG     ###
C       Asia        OCT     ###
```

Desired Output:

```
Product Continent   Month   Sales
A       Asia        AUG 
A       America     AUG 
A       Europe      AUG 
A       Africa      AUG     ###
A       Oceania     AUG 
A       Asia        SEP     ###
A       America     SEP     ###
A       Europe      SEP 
A       Africa      SEP 
A       Oceania     SEP 
A       Asia        OCT 
A       America     OCT 
A       Europe      OCT     ###
A       Africa      OCT 
A       Oceania     OCT     ###
B       Asia        SEP 
B       America     SEP 
B       Europe      SEP     ###
B       Africa      SEP     ###
B       Oceania     SEP 
C       Asia        AUG 
C       America     AUG     ###
C       Europe      AUG 
C       Africa      AUG 
C       Oceania     AUG     ###
C       Asia        OCT     ###
C       America     OCT 
C       Europe      OCT 
C       Africa      OCT 
C       Oceania     OCT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `cross join` to generate the rows and `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select pm.product, pm.month, c.continent, d.sales
from (select distinct continent from data) c cross join
     (select distinct product, month from data) pm left join
     data d
     on d.continent = c.continent and
        d.product = pm.product and
        d.month = pm.month;
```

Comment: Knew it'd be something simple. Never heard of cross joins - I'll look into them now. Cheers!!!

Comment: @Hillsy7 . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: Edit: Ignore me @Gordon, I have no idea how I managed it, but I tagged something wrong and it's working now. Thanks.